# Left function on two columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this piece of code: I would like to do a left function on cells G and M in the following code: I am having an issue as when I try:

```
 If left(.Cells(i, "G",4)) <> left(.Cells(i, "M",4)) this does not work.
```

any advice?

Here is the full code:

```
Sub SingleTradeMove()

 Dim wsTD As Worksheet
 Set wsTD = Worksheets("Trade data")

 Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:AK600").ClearContents

 With wsTD

 lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 For i = 2 To lastRow

    If .Cells(i, "G") <> .Cells(i, "M") _
        Or .Cells(i, "I") <> .Cells(i, "O") _
        Or .Cells(i, "L") <> .Cells(i, "R") Then

       .Cells(i, "J").EntireRow.Copy _
           Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" &
     Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

     End If

    Next i

   End With

  End Sub
```

Comment: It's probably not the best answer (which is why I've only left it as a comment) but surely you could do: `strG = left(.Cells(i, "G",4))` and `strM = left(.Cells(i, "M",4))` in order to do `If strG <> strM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use

```
If left(.Cells(i, "G"),4) <> left(.Cells(i, "M"),4)
```

Comment: Good spot, for some reason I just assumed the right number of arguments in `Cells()` had been used!